# Paypal express checkout redirects

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I implemented paypal express checkout server side and for the most part it works just fine. But, some customers complain that the purchase doesn't work for them. When requesting a screenshot of the problematic window, I noticed that the user was redirected to www.example.com/your_redirect_url.html?paymentId=...&token=...&PayerId=...

I never really populated those redirect urls, because my understanding was that they are not being called. Instead the requests returns to the javascript that called it - which works like this in most cases.

Why does paypal sometimes call the redirect urls? And what should I do when it does that?

Thanks,
Lev